# Please do not flag as low quality for no reason

Tags: discussion, flagging

Please read this question and its answers first:

[Regarding "Low Quality" flag](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2545/regarding-low-quality-flag)

#### The problem:

I've noticed that a small number of users on this site regularly flag questions as low quality, when there is no actual evidence to support this. I'll hold off calling it annoying, but seeing as it is the job of the moderators to respond to these flags, I would still like to point out that we do not enjoy having to handle misflags.

Occasional misflags are okay, but doing it repeatedly is uncalled for. I guess what I'm trying to say is, please desist.

P.S. if it's just a minor formatting issue, editing the question is your best bet. Flagging it (with no explanation as to why) will simply leave us to scratch our heads until we conclude exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Reject flag with a custom message directly to the user creating them?

Comment: @BrunoPereira true.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Agreed. It's a poorly named flag. I wish it was more like this:

> #### Unsalvageably Bad
>
> No number of edits can save this illegible excuse of a post so let's agree to douse it in petrol and set it alight as an example to others.
> This is reserved for posts that are beyond meaningful editing.

If it's just poorly formatted, or could do with some help with grammar, **edit the post**. That's a much more useful thing for everybody involved.

Comment: Wow!! This makes the meaning of Low Quality Flag so-so-so much clear... May I request you to post this on Meta Stack Overflow as a feature-request? Otherwise, let me know and I would do so Community-Wiking the feature-request on MSO.

Comment: Posted at MSO: [Rename “Very Low Quality” Flag as “Unsalvageably Bad”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181166/rename-very-low-quality-flag-as-unsalvageably-bad)